# Laravel controller returning index view instead of json response

Tags: jquery, laravel, apache2

I am using apache2 and php artisan serve command to test my project.

Have the next controller:

```
<?php
// file: Http\Controllers\AuthCtrl.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User; //  <--
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [ 'email' => 'required|exists:users',
                   'password'  => 'required' ];

        $request->validate($rules);

        $data = [ 'email' => $request->get('email'),
                  'password'  =>  $request->get('password') ];

        if( Auth::attempt($data) )
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            // the $user->createToken('appName')->accessToken generates the JWT token that we can use
            return response()->json([
                                      'user'  =>  $user, // <- we're sending the user info for frontend usage
                                      'token' =>  $user->createToken('teltask')->accessToken, // <- token is generated and sent back to the front end
                                      'success' => true
                                    ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                                    'success' => false,
                                    'msg' => 'Credenciales erroneas.'
                                    ]);
        }

    }
}
```

And a simple mock index.php that does an ajax call with the following js:

```
function ExecLogin()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login",
        data : {email : "fsd@gmail.com", password: "mypass"}
    }).done(
    function(data, status) 
    {
        if(data.success == true)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('appname_token', data.token);
            // the following part makes sure that all the requests made later with jqXHR will automatically have this header.
            $( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
                jqxhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + data.token); 
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    }).fail(function(error){
        // handle the error
    });
}
```

As you can see, when the code enters this part, (when the user authenticated OK), It returns a JSON response allright:

```
$user = Auth::user();
            // the $user->createToken('appName')->accessToken generates the JWT token that we can use
            return response()->json([
                                      'user'  =>  $user, // <- we're sending the user info for frontend usage
                                      'token' =>  $user->createToken('teltask')->accessToken, // <- token is generated and sent back to the front end
                                      'success' => true
                                    ]);
```

But when it did not authenticated OK, it enters at this part, but the response is the index.php text/html, not a json response as I defined:

```
return response()->json([
                          'success' => false,
                          'msg' => 'Credenciales erroneas.'
                                    ]);
```

I am recieving the following string on the data object of the ajax call:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
                            <div class="top-right links">
                                            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login">Login</a>

                                                    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/register">Register</a>
                                                            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"
```

Am I missing something important here?

Authenticate Middleware looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson() ) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you check that the response id text/html? Did you look at the response or the ajax call to `/api/login`? Check what is the response returned when a post request with invalid credentials is sent to `/api/login` - in network tab of devtools and by console logging in the js snippet of the index.php

Comment: I am doing exactly that, it returns the html page of index.php. let me put it on the question.

Comment: Thats it, I never had this problem before with production servers, so Im asumming It must be a php artisan serve thing with local development.

Comment: Check what's the content of `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` redirectTo()

Comment: protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson() ) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

Comment: I will put it in the question.

Comment: if you do php artisan route:list, can you post it for the route you created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.
First I tried setting a response header because of the:

```
if (! $request->expectsJson() )
```

So the request only accepts json responses.
Then I got a:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

So I went and looked at the validator in controller:

changed this:

```
$rules = [ 'email' => 'required|exists:users',
           'password'  => 'required' ];
```

to this:

```
$rules = [ 'email' => 'required',
           'password'  => 'required' ];
```

And it worked like a charm.
I think that validation expected an already existing User object, but I was passing a non existing user (bad credentials).
I guess that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm enduring the same problem developing the `create` actions in my API.
I think the problem is answered here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors.

Keeping it to the point: "So, what if the incoming request fields do not pass the given validation rules? As mentioned previously, **Laravel will automatically redirect the user back to their previous location.** In addition, all of the validation errors and request input will automatically be flashed to the session".

Taking into account I haven't created any front-end yet, there are no custom views, so Laravel redirects the request to the standard "Welcome" view.